# Date input being output as null

Tags: java, date, datetime, simpledateformat, date-parsing

I get my output as null when I input date as String

this is the get and set

```
public Date getData(){
    return data;
}

public void setData(String dataRecebida) {
    try { 
      this.data = formatter.parse(dataRecebida);
    } catch(Exception e) {
    }
}
```

```
public Date data; //= "18/09/2019";
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH/dd/MM/yyyy");
```

this is where I input the date

```
System.out.println("E-Digite a data do evento: horario/ dia/mes/Ano");
          evento.setData(sc.nextLine());
```

then, when I do

```
System.out.println("Date:"+evento.getData());
```

I get data output as null

Comment: Your input has the wrong format which crashes `parse`."18/09/2019" does not correspond to "HH/dd/MM/yyyy".

Comment: I'd say `18/09/2019` doesn't correspond to `HH/dd/MM/yyyy` which you would have noticed on the first run if you didn't swallow `Exception` with that empty catch-all block.

Comment: What Frederico and Basil already said. Never swallow exceptions. **Never, ever** do `catch (Exception e) { }` (unless you *absolutely* know what you're doing, and then insert a comment line to explain). You are suppressing exceptions which contain very useful information of what went wrong and where.

Comment: I strongly recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: More precisely, for a date without time of day use `LocalDate`. For a date with hour of day use `LocalDateTime`.

Answer (score 1):

As the Comments have said:

Your  formatting pattern does not match the user’s input text.

You would have known that but for swallowing the thrown exception.

```
catch(Exception e) {
}
```

*Never* write a `catch` that does nothing. (Unless in an unusual situation you really expect an exception. And even then, write a code comment saying so.)

Another problem: You are using terrible date-time classes that are now legacy. They were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Define your formatting pattern with `DateTimeFormatter`. For a date only, use `LocalDate`. For a date with time of day but lacking the context of a time zone or offset from UTC, use `LocalDateTime`.

Search Stack Overflow to learn more. These classes have been covered many many times already.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a small modification in formatter like following:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH");
```

and provide input accordingly **"18/09/2019 00"** this will work but using `LocalDate` or `LocalDateTime` would better approach.